# ComponentActivity can only be called from within the same library group prefix

Tags: android, android-activity, components

I have a working simple Android app with `MainActivity` of `AppCompatActivity`.
I changed to `ComponentActivity` and it generates the following warning.

> ComponentActivity can only be called from within the same library
> group prefix (referenced groupId=androidx.core with prefix androidx
> from groupId=Compose play)

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            MessageCard(Message("Hello", "J C"))
        }
    }
}
```

But the app still compiles and runs normally. Is there any way to resolve this other than `@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")`? Thanks

Comment: It seems like you've imported the wrong `ComponentActivity`. Are you importing `androidx.activity.ComponentActivity`?

Comment: Oh yes! Thanks it is true

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've imported the wrong ComponentActivity. Make sure you are importing `androidx.activity.ComponentActivity`